# Json Encoding returning weird encodes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following to get json data from a web service the the mvc web site which I produced is creating codes for the &; character how do i make sure that i can decode that from using the method below.

```
public async Task<List<BomLookupModel>> GetBomLookups()
{

        List<BomLookupModel> _result = new List<BomLookupModel>();
        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.GetBomLookupInfo, string.Empty));

            var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BomLookupModel>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            Log.Warn(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return _result.ToList();
    }
```

I am not totally sure if it is & im assuming that from the orginal data which had a & char in it.

For Example

```
{"Reference":"GYNE-D\u0026C","Description":"D\u0026C"},
```

This is my webservice method that I am calling from the above.

```
[HttpGet]      

public ActionResult GetBomLookup()
{
        List<BomLookupModel> result = new List<BomLookupModel>();
        result = database.GetBomLookupCodes();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: So, that encoding exists in what's returned from `database.GetBomLookupCodes`. Are you doing it yourself, or is it using URL encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is related with the encoding of that `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`.

So I suggest you doing this:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BomLookupModel>>(content);
}
```